# How to correct Modified Date in Files/Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, files, date

How do I get Nautilus/Files to display the correct modified date?

I just noticed that when my camera's RAW files, the modified date displays a date 31 days in the future! Please refer to the screenshot:
[image: Wrong Nautilus/Files Modified Date]

In Darktable, the EXIF file shows the correct date. When I plug-in the SD card, it will immediately display 07 November and that's a bit annoying, especially when I am trying to organise my files.